# Devise Rails - Strange password reset error without proper notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, forgot-password

I am using Rails 4.1.5 and devise 3.4.1 and have the following problem with reseting my passwords.....

[image: This is the correct password login screen]

After I enter the new password and press enter I get the following...(Note: on the account the password was changed successfully, but a user would never know this based on this output unless they had the tenacity to try the new password)

[image]

In my interpretation it is changing the password correctly and reloading the page, so the error message may be valid BUT it should display that the reset was successful!

I can also post my edit.html.erb or devise.en.yml or devise.rb if that is helpful....I'm totally stuck and don't understand where to start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018657/rails-4-devise-password-reset-is-always-giving-a-token-is-invalid-error-on

Comment: This is my code - '<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>'. I think that SO post is before my issue