# Rails console can't find Devise reset_password_token (debugging 'Reset password token is invalid')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Perhaps I'm tired and missing something obvious, but I'm seeing the strangest things trying to debug 'Reset password token is invalid' on Rails 4.1.16, Devise 3.5.10 and Ruby 2.3.8.

I'm aware of and have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018657/rails-4-devise-password-reset-is-always-giving-a-token-is-invalid-error-on) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3431). Trying to reproduce the reset password steps in console, I'm wondering if there's a more fundamental error with my app.

I can run `u.send_reset_password_instructions` which happily creates the `reset_password_token`, commits it to the DB, and sends a hashed version in the password reset email.

`SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_sent_at" = ?, "reset_password_token" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 8  [["reset_password_sent_at", "2018-11-10 03:35:39.176325"], ["reset_password_token", "a8e9f1dd874735078fc79dbf1a72a5546edf12915eea604bc29e7da897de3c6e"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-10 03:35:39.176799"]]`

So we have a reset_password_token of `a8e9f1dd874735078fc79dbf1a72a5546edf12915eea604bc29e7da897de3c6e` which Devise has hashed to `NUY_d-cz4GsaCBJz-LPy` for use in the email. All good so far.

However, if I run `User.with_reset_password_token("NUY_d-cz4GsaCBJz-LPy")`, the hash is correctly decoded and the DB finds... nothing:

`User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = 'a8e9f1dd874735078fc79dbf1a72a5546edf12915eea604bc29e7da897de3c6e'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => nil`

So then I try a manual search in the console for the exact same query: `User.find_by(reset_password_token: "a8e9f1dd874735078fc79dbf1a72a5546edf12915eea604bc29e7da897de3c6e")`

And I get... Nothing:

`User Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = 'a8e9f1dd874735078fc79dbf1a72a5546edf12915eea604bc29e7da897de3c6e' LIMIT 1
 => nil`

I am sure this is at the root of the problems I'm having with 'Reset password token is invalid', but I can't figure out why the DB search is failing on such a simple thing. Is there something obvious I should be checking?

Comment: What does `User.find(8)` return for that field?

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't return that field!

Comment: Is this because certain fields are only available to Devise or something?

Comment: Are you certain the database transaction isn’t being rolled back?

Comment: Yes, because I can see it via SQLite - the DB field is definitely there and populated in the users table, but not being returned by the user model on `User.find`. I'll do some more digging...